# How to show the upload progress in Windows Phone application (C#)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I'm trying to achieve one thing. I want to show a progress status of uploading file. Server-side accepts multipart requests.

Other applications, which run under Android & iOS are showing progress percentage perfectly, using the same server-side, which I'm trying to use in my Windows Phone application.

I can upload file using `RestSharp` library or `HttpClient`, but I can't find way hot to show the percentage of uploaded file.

I've tried to search the way of doing this, but no success. `ExecuteAsync` method, doesn't provide some kind of callback function, in which I can show the current status of uploaded file.

Also, there is some stuff `Background file transfers` by name (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx), but it's rather difficult, but I'm trying to understand it.

I have seen, that such aim is easy to solve in Android or iOS. I think Microsoft products for Windows Phone are miles better, and there must be well libraries, which would provide me possibility to show status in percentages of uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is some pseudo code, the trick for the progress is in the `Progress<DownloadOperation>` handler:

```
Uri uri = ...
StorageFile storageFile = ...
CancellationTokenSource cts = ...

BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, storageFile);

Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(OnDownloadPregress);


await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
```